# How to install ftx with pip?

Tags: python, cmd, pip, package

I'm trying to install ftx package on my Windows through the command prompt using pip and I'm getting a long error message, probably linked to the package ciso8601. I have tried to do 'pip install ciso8601' independently but I get the same error message. If I run my python script anyway, I understandably get an error message stating that ftx module is not installed.

Here's the error message I get in the prompt :

```
C:\Users\Hugo>pip install ftx
Collecting ftx
  Using cached ftx-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.0 kB)
Collecting ciso8601
  Using cached ciso8601-2.2.0.tar.gz (18 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\hugo\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->ftx) (2021.10.8)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: ciso8601
  Building wheel for ciso8601 (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgk2o8g5k'
       cwd: C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3tymq2i_\ciso8601_bf92ed427eec43fcb523ddbb3aa3e096
  Complete output (70 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'ciso8601\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\ciso8601
  copying ciso8601\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\ciso8601
  copying ciso8601\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\ciso8601
  running build_ext
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 230, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 37, in <module>
      setup(
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 79, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 202, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
      objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 327, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 224, in initialize
      vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 316, in msvc14_get_vc_env
      return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bhob0b89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 270, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
      raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
  setuptools._distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ciso8601
Failed to build ciso8601
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ciso8601, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
pip3 install ftx
```

command so that uses python version 3 to install. This may fix the syntax issue

You may also want to install Microsoft C++ 14.0 or higher as it asks you to here->

```
setuptools._distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

You can do it from this URL: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/